# Fullcalendar permit selectOverlap for one day

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using Fullcalendar and I need to allow event overlap for one day: the last still event day can overlap on the first new event day.

For resizing and drop I resolved in this way:

```
eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
    var a = movingEvent.start.startOf('day'); 
    var b = stillEvent.end.startOf('day');
    if(a.unix() == b.unix()){
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Now I need to do the same on selecting, according to [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectOverlap/), I have to use `selectOverlap` option by define a function, but differently of `eventOverlap`, this function not have an argument that include the current selection period, then I don't know how to make the check.

Somebody can say me how to do so?

**UPDATE 19/05/2017:**
I opened an issue on github's project repository [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/312)

Comment: can you please share the link/url of your implementation (codepen)?

Comment: @Adeel I'm sorry but my code is half generated from C# server control and export it to plain html/js It's too much work

Comment: @gidanmx2 you could just use View Source on final your rendered page in the browser to very easily copy/paste it out